# functionpointer declaration. With or without variable name?

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I am currently stiring the legacy spaghetti and have found a declaration I cannot find an explanation for.
So far I seen and used functionpointer in which you declare the pointer and add in brackets the datatype(s) of the function arguments( see 1. ). Now I have found a declaration including the variable Name of the function ( see 2. ).
`void function(int var) { ... }`

1. `void (*function_ptr)(int) = &function;`
2. `void (*function_ptr)(int var) = &function;`

Is there a difference in functionality or anything else? Or is this just a style difference?
As far as I know it makes no difference when calling the function over either of the pointer declarations.
e.g.:  `function_ptr(5);`

Comment: You are right. They are same in semantics,  just a style difference.

Comment: When declaring a function or function pointer, you can omit the names of the arguments.  The only place where you need to include the names is in the function definition, i.e. when the function body is present (since it needs names so it can reference the arguments).

Comment: Technically speaking a function is **always** called via a pointer to a function. A function name is transformed to a function pointer just before the function call.

Comment: @TomKarzes "can omit the names of the arguments" better as "can omit the names of the parameters".  parameter:  object declared as part of a function declaration or definition that acquires a value on entry to the function, or ...

Comment: @tstanisl "a function is always called via a pointer"  --> no [inline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function) functions in C?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, inline functions provide function's body for optimization. The function name decays to function pointer in the C abstract machine prior to the function call.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Well, I meant "formal arguments", for which "parameters" is a synonym.  I assumed it was clear from the context.

Answer (score 2):

Just like you can *declare* a function with or without parameter names, you can write a function pointer type with or without parameter names. There is no semantic difference.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(int); // declaration without parameter name

int main() {
    int (*p1)(int i) = foo; // function pointer with parameter name
    int (*p2)(int) = foo; // function pointer without parameter name

    printf("%d %d", p1(2), p2(1));
}

int foo(int i); // declaration with parameter name

int foo(int i) { // definition
    return i%2 == 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6rs6ccq6n)

I tend to omit parameter names in function pointer types because function pointers can be assigned different functions. Function declarations should include the same parameter names as their corresponding definitions for the sake of understanding what the parameters represent.

Comment: @Lundin That's a little harsh when only the example is wrong. The rest applies to both C and C++. In any case, thanks for pointing it out, I fixed it.

Comment: Or so it just happened to be... `void (*p)()` has a different meaning between C and C++. C++ supports function overloading. C supports all manner of legacy styles (at least til C23). And so on.

Comment: Given that the question is about parameter names, it doesn't make much sense to talk about functions with no parameters (or I guess an empty parameter list). I can't think of anything else that differs between C and C++ in this context.

Answer (score 1):

The variable name `var` in the declaration of the function pointer serves no other purpose than to provide some clarity to the readers of the code. The two declarations are otherwise equivalent.

Comment: And that clarity is very useful when (to quote the OP) *stirring the legacy spaghetti*